# How to add a contact form to a static web site?

Tags: forms, server-side

I have a mostly "static" web site with no server-side code and just a little JavaScript. Now I would like to add a contact form. I do not care how I get the contact form data (so just writing this data to a text file in the server will be ok).

What is the *simplest* solution for this problem? How do people usually handle this?

I believe I can add some server-side code (PHP or something) to handle the form (and write the form data to a file, for instance) but I would prefer a client-side solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an external tool, they are commonly referred to as "[formmailer](http://www.google.com/search?q=formmailer)". You basically submit the form to their server, and they send the form contents via mail to you.

If you don't want that, you have to do something server-sided: Storing data on the server, without having a server side program that accepts the data from the client, is just not possible.

---

You could install CouchDB and interface that from Javascript :) Everyone could use that then, too :)

---

The most easy PHP script that stores POST data on your harddisk:

```
<?php file_put_contents('/path/to/file', serialize($_POST) . "\n", FILE_APPEND); ?>
```

Comment: Is there other options of contact form handling w/o coding? Suppose I do not have to get the data as an email.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Drive and create form with required fields. and embed code (which will be iframe) in your static web page. 
You will be able to get submitted data in spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [qontacto](http://www.qontacto.com) . it is a free contact form you can add to any website. it forwards you the messages.

Answer (score 0):

I set up the [fwdform](http://samdobson.github.io/fwdform/) service for this exact need.

Just two simple steps to get your form forwarded to your email.

### 1.Register

Make an HTTP POST request to register your email.

```sh
$ curl --data "email=<your_email>" https://fwdform.herokuapp.com/register
Token: 780a8c9b-dc2d-4258-83af-4deefe446dee
```

### 2. Set up your form

```html
<form action="https://fwdform.herokuapp.com/user/<token>" method="post">
    Email: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Name: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    Message: <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
</form>
```

With a couple of extra seconds you can [spin up your own instance](http://samdobson.github.io/fwdform/#privacy-concerns) on Heroku.